# Extension cord's power socket grounding pin soaked in cleaning agent sud, what is a proper way of cleaning?

Tags: short-circuit, water, humidity

I didn't really know what tags to use. Anyways, this might sound stupid, however I was cleaning up something above the extension cord which was laying on the ground, and while I pressed the wipe suds and agent dripped into the grounding socket, nothing as far as I am aware. Now I don't know what can corrode and what can go bad, however this was a cleaning agent with the common Benzalkonium chloride 0.75g/100 g and among others: <5% amphoteric surfacatans, buthylphenyl methylpropional, Linaool, perfume.

It is a pretty good surge protecting extension cord though, so I don't really wanna throw it. I am not sure how to "cure" it and what damaged I might've done. Few hours has passed and I haven't turned it on - although it is plugged at the wall right now. I cleaned it with a q-tip and a bit of water few times, the color is now gone when wiping, but of course a bit of the moisture went inside. It wasn't a terrible amount, more like few milliliters though.

Comment: What Jasen says. Clean with something (Alcohol 60%+ or water). Leave somewhere warm till fully dry. PROBABLY now fine. Optional - test with mains and AC microammeter if available to see what leakage is (overkill). OR place somewhere safe, apply mains, leave a day. If no flames smoke bad smell it is PROVAVLY OK . And probably OK as is. Note - this is commemt. YMMV but probably won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably fine as is, but to be sure:

rinse with denatured alcohol, shake dry, and allow to sit in a warm place until the alcohol smell is gone (or mostly gone).

Comment: What would be different if I use a rubbing alcohol with over 70% (maybe 90%) ethanol? What alternatives would you suggest if denatured is not available to purchase, does the evaporation rate matters and that is why you suggest denatured alcohol thus I can simply take a higher % ethanol?

Comment: Should be available at supermarkets and hardware stores.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denatured_alcohol - its main features are 1, non-conductive, 2 absorbs water (and washes it away),  3 volatile (so residue dries fast)  If the rubbing alcohol is 30% water it's going to be a less effective drying agent. rinsing with distilled, or de-ionised water would do the same job, just slower.

Comment: I will try harder to find it, but as I read there can be difference in % of the ingredients, I am guessing everything will work. Distilled water is everywhere though, when you say slower - how much slower?

Comment: one more question, is Isopropyl alcohol as useful as Denatured in such case?

Comment: should be about the same, yeah